# Recursion in VHDL, performance? what is the difference with a conventional programming language?

Tags: vhdl

I've seen in the Ashenden book that recursion in VHDL is possible... however i was wandering how should i look at recursion in terms of performance? In conventional progrmaming language the recursion imply stack memory using, which as example could go in overflow in extreme cases...

Be careful that the recursion i mean that we could have a design with a `generic` parameter `n` and with such parameter we could know at compilation time the deep of the recursion (so it isn't in real time actually, like in conventional programming language i mean).

Pro and cons of vhdl recursion?

Comment: "imply stack memory using" entirely dependend on the implementation and type of recursion being used. With tail recursion you can optimize stack usage away

Comment: Could you elaborate more?

Comment: It's possible as long as the resursion depth is limited pre-synthesis. Only pro I can think of is convenience - It's quicker to code. I don't imagine there would be any performance advantage, since AFAIK the hw implementation would be the same either way.

Comment: So assuming a design could be implemented both iteratively or recursively there's neither disadvantage or advantage in choosing on design or another? (i've an example that i could post but i don't want to go off topic). I mean i have a design that i would like to implement (for sake of practice) and i can't think entirely in terms of iteration, but more in terms of recursion.

Comment: The synthesis tool is going to expand/flatten out (for lack of a better word) the recursion in any case during synthesis. This is why the depth needs to be known beforehand. It shouldn't matter if you do it or leave it to the synthesis tool

Answer (score 3):

Recursion is possible in VHDL as long as the maximum depth is known and specified beforehand. The synthesis tool should expand out the recursion in any case. As for pros and cons, I can only think of one difference, and that's convenience for the user. Whichever way is most convenient should be fine. If it's easier to think about and develop an algorithm using recursion, then coding it that way would be easier and less error prone. The converse is true too.